# has_and_belongs_to_many gives "no such table" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a many-to_many relationship between dossier and contact and therefore they have has_and_belongs_to_many relationship:

```
class Dossier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
```

and

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dossiers
```

In the Dossiers controller show method I have this:

```
@dossier = current_user.company.dossiers.find(params[:id])    
@dossier_contacts = @dossier.contacts
```

But when I request the show view, I get the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: contacts_dossiers: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts" INNER JOIN "contacts_dossiers" ON "contacts"."id" = "contacts_dossiers"."contact_id" WHERE "contacts_dossiers"."dossier_id" = 1
```

The view looks like this:

```
<li><%= I18n.t :dossier_nr_contacts %></li><li><%= @dossier_contacts.count.to_s %></li>
```

I think I have set the relationship correct, the table exists, but I don't now why it gives the error. Any clues?

Edit: The migration I did:

```
class CreateDossiersContactsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :dossiers_contacts, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :dossier_id
      t.integer :contact_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :dossiers_contacts
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you know the table exists? SQLite3 appears to disagree with you. Eg, do a `rake db:schema:dump` again to be sure, then look at `db/schema.rb`. Your rails stuff doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: in `has_and_belong_to_many` association there are involved 3 tables, and you are missing the link table.create a new migration called `contacts_dossiers` with 2 columns `contact_id` and `dossier_id` and an index on each column, run db:migrate. More about habtm http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association (look at the picture => 3 tables)

Comment: I did execute a migration (see edited post above) and the table does exist in the database, I already checked that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your join table's name is wrong.

It should be `contacts_dossiers` (alphabetical order by default)

> If you create a has_and_belongs_to_many association, you need to explicitly create the joining table. Unless the name of the join table is explicitly specified by using the `:join_table` option, Active Record creates the name by using the lexical order of the class names. So a join between customer and order models will give the default join table name of “customers_orders” because “c” outranks “o” in lexical ordering.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has_and_belongs_to_many-associations

Comment: Yes, found the same after googling and it indeed makes the difference, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your using `has_and_belongs_to_many` you alsways need an association table which holds the id pairs for you. By convention this table is called like plural of both tables joined! In your example `contacts_dossiers`.

You need to create this table. Create a migration and create the table like this:

```
create_table :contacts_dossiers, :id => false do |f|
     f.integer :contact_id, :dossier_id
end
```

Then migrate the table and everything should work!

Comment: Have you tryed to connect to the db with the SQLite Concole and checked if the table does really exist?

Comment: Try to add the `:join_table => 'contacts_dossiers'` option to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. YOu need to do this in both models!